# creating a fake file that shows the output of a program

Tags: linux, fuse

I am trying to "stich" two programs together. The first program, which I can change as I want, generates an output with some data. The second program cannot be changed, and expects to read the data that is generated by the first program.

This second program exects a file, I cannot use a pipe. I don't want to regenerate the file every x seconds.

Is there a way on linux to create a "fake" file that fetches the first program output every time it's opened for reading? This would be transparent to the second program. Is it doable with fuse?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `bash`, you can [use process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
program2 <(program1)
```

If you're not using a shell with process substitution, you can use a named pipe.

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
program1 > /tmp/pipe &
program2 /tmp/pipe
```

Many programs that require a filename argument for their input also allow that filename to be `-`, which they interpret to mean standard input. This allows you to pipe to them:

```
program1 | program2 -
```